# How to store a multidimentional array to simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array as seen below.

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [key-1] => Array
        (
            [key-1-1] => 33
            [key-1-2] => 22
        )

    [key-2] => -1

    [key-3] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [other_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => data1
                            [1] => data2
                        )
                )

        )

    [key-4] => data3
    [key-5] => data4
)
```

I need to convert these in simpler form of end values as given below and save to an external php file using file_put_contents . I am trying for hours and I tried var_export, multiple foreach and got some degree of success, but not exactly what I want.

```
$value['key-1-1'] = '33';
$value['key-1-2'] = '22';
$value['other_data'] = array('data1', 'data2');
$value['key-4'] = 'data3';
$value['key-5'] = 'data4';
```

Can someone help with achieving it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get somewhat near to your desired output with array_walk_recursive.  The troublesome keys are the numeric ones.

If you only have one other_data sub arrays, you could slightly adjust the output below.  You'll get overwritten values for like numeric keys.  So this method really depends on your data.

```
<?php

$data = 
array
(
    '0' =>'',
    'key-1' => array
        (
            'key-1-1' => 33,
            'key-1-2' => 22
        ),
    'key-2' => -1,
    'key-3' => array
        (
            'data' => array
                (
                    'other_data' => array
                        (
                            '0' => 'data1',
                            '1' => 'data2'
                        )
                )
        ),
    'key-4' => 'data3',
    'key-5' => 'data4'
);

array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$result) {
    $result[$k] = $v;
});

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'data1',
    'key-1-1' => 33,
    'key-1-2' => 22,
    'key-2' => -1,
    1 => 'data2',
    'key-4' => 'data3',
    'key-5' => 'data4',
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your advise to create the solution of my issue.